# Splitting up complex json-encoded string

Tags: r, json, string

I have a data frame with a string in it like so:

```
df <- tibble(user_id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), 
             string = c("[{\"question_id\":\"question_name_cd_1_NB\",\"answers\":[\"0\"]}]",
             "[{\"question_id\":\"question_name_2_ND\",\"answers\":[\"2\"]}]",
             "[{\"question_id\":\"question_name_3_ML\",\"answers\":[\"3\"]}]",
             "[{\"question_id\":\"question_name_ll_4\",\"answers\":[\"2\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_5\",\"answers\":[\"0\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_6|1\",\"answers\":[\"7\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_6|2\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_cd_1_NB\",\"answers\":[\"4\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_PN|2\",\"answers\":[\"6\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_PN|6\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_lw\",\"answers\":[\"99\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_lw|2\",\"answers\":[\"98\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_PN|3\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_x\",\"answers\":[\"32\"]}]",   
             "[{\"answers\":[\"1\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_3_ML\"}]",
             "[{\"answers\":[\"7\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_3_ML\"}]",
             "[{\"question_id\":\"question_name_ll_4\",\"answers\":[\"1\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_5\",\"answers\":[\"11\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_6|2\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_6|1\",\"answers\":[\"2\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_cd_1_NB\",\"answers\":[\"14\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_reason_X2|3\",\"answers\":[\"3\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_PN|2\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_lw\",\"answers\":[\"1\"]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_PN|3\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_lw_reason_SS|2\",\"answers\":[]},{\"question_id\":\"question_name_x\",\"answers\":[\"6\"]}]",    
             "[{\"answers\":[\"2\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_cd_1_NB\"},{\"answers\":[\"9\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_lw\"},{\"answers\":[\"1\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_x\"},{\"answers\":[\"6\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_6|1\"},{\"answers\":[\"5\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_ll_4\"},{\"answers\":[\"2\"],\"question_id\":\"question_name_5\"}]"))
```

There is no identifiable pattern in the `question_id`s. I've changed the names from what they are in my actual `df`, but they could have 1 underscore `_`, or many, they could have alphabetic and numeric characters, or just numeric, and they could have `|` characters within them. They do not actual start with `question_name` as i've shown in the toy data above.

There can sometimes be only one `question_id` per user or there can be many, and sometimes a question's corresponding `answers` value comes before the question and sometimes after it.

What I would like to do is split out the questions and answers per `user_id`, so each `user_id` as many times as there are questions for that user. For example, based on the data above, that would mean `user_id == A` has only one row, whereas `user_id == H` would have six rows.

The final df would have three columns, one for user ID, one for question_id and one for the answer.

Does anyone know how I can solve for this? It feels like a regular expression problem but one that is way beyond my current abilities.

Comment: It looks like your `string` column is JSON-encoded.  Does `jsonlite::fromJSON(df$string[7])` get you close to what you'd need for user G?  If so, we might be able to build on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your question, and your data, something like this should work

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

df %>% 
  pmap_dfr(function(user_id, string) {
    fromJSON(string) %>% 
      mutate(user_id = user_id) %>% 
      select(user_id, question_id, answers)
  })
```

Working from the inside out, the most important part is the `fromJSON()` call.  Your `string` column seems to be in JSON format - try `jsonlite::fromJSON(df$string[7])` to see the result on the data for user G.  The `mutate` just adds the `user_id` to the data for each user, and the `select` reorders the columns.  The `pmap_dfr` just calls the function for each row, and combines them into a single data frame.

Comment: A little more neatly - `map_df(setNames(df$string, df$user_id), fromJSON, .id = "user")`.

Comment: A little? ROFL.  That's much more succinct.  I figured there'd be a better way, but wasn't expecting a one-liner.  I'd upvote that if you were to post it as an answer.

Comment: This is fantastic though Hobo! I def agree that  27 ϕ 9 's answer is more succinct but as an R noob I actually find yours more readable. Thanks both anyway! I was banging my head against a wall on this for hours

Comment: Ah no, i've just tried this on my actual data and am getting this error: `Error in .f(date = .l[[1L]][[i]], string = .l[[2L]][[i]], user_id = .l[[3L]][[i]],  : 
  unused arguments (date = .l[[1]][[i]], survey_number = .l[[4]][[i]])`. I suspect this is bc I have columns date and survey_number in my df but am not addressing them in the function

Comment: Actually no problem. I just needed to add date and survey_number into the function call and then the mutate and select calls. Thanks again! Super super helpful

Comment: Cool - was about to suggest modifying the function; glad you got there.  Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

I have the same as @Hobo, but with base `apply`:

```
library(jsonlite)

apply(df,1,function(x){
  fromJSON(x["string"]) %>%
    mutate(user_id = x["user_id"])
}) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.)
```

I know, `purrr` makes it easier and more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Map` and `lapply` -

```
library(jsonlite)

res <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, user = df$user_id, lapply(df$string, fromJSON)))
rownames(res) <- NULL
res  

#   user                  question_id answers
#1     A        question_name_cd_1_NB       0
#2     B           question_name_2_ND       2
#3     C           question_name_3_ML       3
#4     D           question_name_ll_4       2
#5     D              question_name_5       0
#6     D            question_name_6|1       7
#7     D            question_name_6|2        
#8     D        question_name_cd_1_NB       4
#9     D           question_name_PN|2       6
#10    D           question_name_PN|6        
#11    D             question_name_lw      99  
#...
#...
```